# Kafka brokers will share same locations to store data logs; if they are in a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I am reading one of the article related to Kafka basics. If one of the Kafka **brokerX** dies in a cluster then, that **brokerX** data copies will move to other live brokers, which are in the cluster.

If that is the case, Is zookeeper/Kafka Controller will copy the brokerX data folder and move to live brokers like copy paste from one machine hard-disc to another (physical copy)?

Or, live brokers will share a common location ? so that will zookeeper/controller will link/point to the brokerX locations(logical copy) ?

[image]

I am little hard in understanding here. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

If a broker dies, it's dead. There's no background process that will copy data off of it

The replication of topics only happens while the broker is running

Plus, that image is wrong. The `partitions = 2` means exactly that. A third partition doesn't just appear when a broker dies

Answer (score 1):

This all depends if the topic has a replication factor > 1. In this case, brokers holding follower replica are constantly sending fetch requests to the leader replica (a specific broker), with a goal of being head to head with the leader (both the follower replica and leader replica having the same records stored on disk).

So when a broker goes down, all it takes is for the controller to select and promote an in-sync replica (by default, but could select non insync replicas) to take over as the leader of the partition. No copy/paste required, all brokers holding a partition(s) (as a follower replica or leader replica) of that topic are storing the same information prior to shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

If a broker dies the behaviour depends on the dead broker. If it was not the leader for its partition it's non problem. when the broker returns on-line it will have to copy all missing data from the leader replica. If the dead broker was the leader for the partition a new leader will be elected according to some rules. If the new elected leader was in sync before the old leader died, there will be no message loss and the follower brokers will sync their replica from the new leader, as the broken leader will do when up again. If the new elected leader was not in sync you might have some message loss. Anyway you can drive the behaviour of your kafka cluster setting various parameters to balance speed, data integrity and reliability.